# NO identities from the profile issue

Tags: ios7, xcode5, provisioning-profile

Hey I have a new machine on which I am installing my provisioning certificate and provisioning profile. When I set the code sing is show that No identities from the profile. I am doing it first time. I do not know why it is not showing the signing identity. Is it developer account issue or any thing else.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little bit unspecific, for people to help you. But lets give it a shot.

1.) Make sure the profisioning profiles are valid for your App (especiall look at the bundle identifier - the must match, or the profile must end with a '.*')

2.) In Xcode 5 goto Preferences / Accounts / View-Details and press the Sync button. If your profiles show up there it should work and they show up in the build settings. (Attention if you are still with Xcode 4, the profiles dialog is somewhre in the Organizer window)

If this brings you one step further, please mark question solved. IF further problems exist, create a more specific question.